# How can I load external DLL while running application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dll

Hello every c# professionals,

I would like to know the way to dynamically load external DLL file as public function which I can call anywhere within my application.

Now I can load DLL like this way:

```
[DllImport("Mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr Mydll_Start(int lpContext, int MAXW, int MAXH, StringBuilder VerInfo);
```

It is works fine but I need to run multiple instances of this dll function for different threads, for example, there is 3 different threads and all threads must call same function at same time.
This dll is not designed for multithreads, so I make copy of this dll files like "Mydll_1.dll", "Mydll_2.dll", "Mydll_3.dll" and load 3 times with different function names like "Mydll_Start_1", "Mydll_Start_2".

But sometimes I need load only 1 dll file or 2, it depends on conditions of my application running, so I want to load these different dll files at runtime when condition is decided. like:

```
int NeedInstancesOfDLL = 0
// some codes to decide needed DLL counts.
...
// load DLLs dynamically.
for (int i=0; i<NeedInstancesOfDLL; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            [DllImport("Mydll_1.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
             public static extern IntPtr Mydll_Start_1(int lpContext, int MAXW, int MAXH, StringBuilder VerInfo);
            break;
        case 1:
            [DllImport("Mydll_2.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
             public static extern IntPtr Mydll_Start_2(int lpContext, int MAXW, int MAXH, StringBuilder VerInfo);
            break;
        case 2:
            [DllImport("Mydll_3.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
             public static extern IntPtr Mydll_Start_3(int lpContext, int MAXW, int MAXH, StringBuilder VerInfo);
            break;
    }
}

// Now I can call each functions from DLL
var RtnVal = Mydll_Start_1(values, values, values)...
```

This is what I want to do but I can't find way to do it.
Above code is of course incomprehensible by compiler.

My point is:

1. How to load different external Dlls while running application.
2. How to declare these external DLLs for runnable functions while running?

Sorry for my seems stupid question but I really can't find the way.
Thanks for all you guys help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by dynamically calling `LoadLibrary`, see for example https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have a question though. My DLL has 3 different functions inside, so I have to declare these all functions and load DLL and unload DLL every time when I call these functions??